# Issue related to HTML Design in BrowserMode : IE9 and DocumentMode: IE7 standard

Tags: html, asp.net, css, internet-explorer, ie-compatibility-mode

i have an asp.net web Application; i have used some telerik controls in my web application

i have an issue related to HTML design in Internet explorer when i use `BrowserMode: IE9 and Document Mode : IE7 Standrd`  HTML design doesn't display properly;

i have used meta tag :

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge" >
```

that solves Compatibility Mode issue but doesn't solve when Document Type is in IE 7 mode

is there any solution ? when page's DocumentType Mode in IE7 Standard Mode ??

THanks

Comment: Setting the `IE=edge` should solve it; that should be enough to avoid compat mode. The only reason you might still end up in compat mode is because of IE's "local intranet" settings; there is a setting that will trigger IE to go into compat mode on local sites. This will include `localhost`, etc, so if you're testing the site on your PC you might hit compat mode, but no-one else will. Turn this setting off to make local sites work the same as the rest of the internet.

Comment: what setting i can try ? i have used IE=9 , IE=8 and IE=7  but still not working.